# Firebird get the list with all available id

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

In a table I have records with id's 2,4,5,8. How can I receive a list with values 1,3,6,7.  I have tried in this way

```
SELECT t1.id + 1
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM table t2
    WHERE t2.id = t1.id + 1
)
```

but it's not working correctly. It doesn't bring all available positions.

Is it possible without another table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all the missing ID's from a recursive CTE, like this:

```
with recursive numbers as (
  select 1 number
    from rdb$database
  union all
  select number+1
    from rdb$database
         join numbers on numbers.number < 1024
)
select n.number
  from numbers n
 where not exists (select 1 
                     from table t
                    where t.id = n.number)
```

the `number < 1024` condition in my example limit the query to the max 1024 recursion depth. After that, the query will end with an error. If you need more than 1024 consecutive *ID's* you have either run the query multiple times adjusting the interval of numbers generated or think in a different query that produces consecutive numbers without reaching that level of recursion, which is not too difficult to write.

Comment: it is correct except the not exists part. 'and' must be replaced with 'where'.+1 and accepted.